# How to fill an array with data starting at index other than 0?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create a firmware update utility that will read the new firmware from a file and send it as packets via USB to an 8-bit microcontroller. The because the packets are sent via i2c it is easiest just to work with the data as a byte array. I'd like each packet to have a format of:

- bytes 0 & 1 = packet number
- bytes 2 - 258 = data
- bytes 259 & 260 = checksum

The problem is that the file's `ReadBytes` function returns the data as a byte array. Rather than have to create multiple large arrays it would be nice to simply this by having the function fill the our packet array starting at index 2. Here's an example in code:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(directory, FileMode.Open));
byte[] packet = new byte[260];

// Create and send packet
for (ushort i = 0; i < numOfPacketsNeeded; i++)
{
    // Set current packet index
    packet[0] = (byte)i;
    packet[1] = (byte)(i >> 8);

    // Start filling at packet[2]
    packet[] = reader.ReadBytes(256);

}
```

My original attempt was to create a "FirmwarePacketModel" where packet.data was it's own array of 256 bytes and index and checksum were ushorts. I didn't like this because it creates a 260 byte model, but then we still have to create a 260 byte array to feed to the USB driver.

The other thing I'm considering would be:

```
for (count = 2; count < 260; count ++)
{
    packet[count] = reader.ReadBytes(1);
}
```

But I worry this seems sloppy & wasteful. What's an effective solution for this?

Comment: The BinaryReader.Read method has an overload Read(byte[], int, int) where the first parameter is the byte array you want to fill, the second the offset to start filling, and the third, the number of bytes to read from the file. Can this be what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.read?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_BinaryReader_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: `reader.Read(packet, 2, 256);`

Comment: @OguzOzgul: Ya, I went this route. Haven't tested it but it looks exactly like what I was needing! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.CopyTo` method to copy from index `2` if buffer is received from other program which cannot be changed.

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(directory, FileMode.Open));
byte[] packet = new byte[262];
// Create and send packet
for (ushort i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Set current packet index
    packet[0] = (byte)i;
    packet[1] = (byte)(i >> 8);

    // Copy read buffer starting index 2 
    reader.ReadBytes(256).CopyTo(packet,2); //starting at index 2
}
```

**Edited:** The `reader.Read()` would be an optimized way as pointed out by @Zereges and mentioned by @OguzOzgul.

```
reader.Read(packet,2, 256);   // Use with caution
```

Comment: This definitely isn't *effective* solution, since you are populating the array just to copy it immediatelly somewhere else

Comment: @Zereges You are correct. If OP is reading from other source then obviously reading to another array and then copying to `packet` is not optimum way.  `reader.Read` from an index would be best `CopyTo` is best suited if OP is getting buffer some other program/library which he cannot change.

Comment: Thank you both! Ya, it's something so simple but I wasn't finding anything 'elegant'. I don't know if it matters but the file being read will be hexadecimal. That seems to rule out ```read.Read()```.

Comment: @liquidair You are welcome. If data read is `hexadecimal` then you can use either method as every character (as represented in file) will be 1 byte long.

Comment: The data read is bytes, no matter what the format of the file is. reader.Read(byte[], int, int) seems to be the optimal solution here since it does not create a clone of the array (reader.ReadBytes creates a new array). The return value of reader.Read() should be checked though. It will return the actual number of bytes read, meaning, if the file contents is exhausted, the last block may read less than 256 bytes. In that case, and since we do not clear the 'byte[] packet' before passing it to reader.Read(), extra caution must be taken.

Comment: BinaryReader reads bytes, not chars. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @OguzOzgul Not at all. `reader.Read(byte[], int, int)` copies bytes into buffer and it is same as `readbytes`. My comments were more towards `reader.Read(char[], int, int)` overloaded function. Probably that has caused confusion. Let me remove it. Thanks.